# Elegant proof of $e^{nf}=\cosh(n)+\sinh(n)f$ where $f^2=1$

Tags: proof-writing, exponential-function

The following transition comes up in various physics texts, often without explanation, so I was wondering if there is a nice way to prove it:

Given $n$ and $f$ such that $f^2=1$, we have 
$$e^{nf}=\cosh(n)+\sinh(n)f$$

I managed to prove it through series expansion, but it is far from elegant.

I tried to make sense of a different way of viewing it, $$e^{nf}=\frac {e^n+e^{-n}}2+\frac {e^n-e^{-n}}2f$$

but I still don't see it.

Any idea?

Comment: $\;f^2=1 \iff f = \pm1\,$ so there are only two cases to verify.

Comment: (But if we're working over the [split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) which have an element $j \ne \pm 1$ with $j^2 =1$, then we're probably forced to use series expansion, because otherwise we don't even know what $e^{nj}$ is.)

Comment: @dxiv True, thanks! I am used to seeing this "$1$" as a matrix or an operator, so it didn't come to mind naturally.

Comment: I fear, in at least some of those physics texts, $f$ can be from some Clifford algebra, or worse. Then, as @MishaLavrov notes, there is only a way via series expansion. Cases when $f^2=1$ implies $f=\pm1$ is too easy even for a physics text to mention explicitly at all. ;)

Comment: I've edited my answer based on your comments. What do you think now? @MishaLavrov

Comment: And also @arseniiv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\cosh(n)=\frac{e^n+e^{-n}}{2}$$
$$\sinh(n)=\frac{e^n-e^{-n}}{2}$$
There is only 2 possible $f$ value, so it's easy to check for both, Let's start with $f=1$:
$$\cosh(n)+\sinh(n)=\frac{e^n+e^{-n}}{2}+\frac{e^n-e^{-n}}{2}=2\frac{e^n}{2}+\frac{e^{-n}}{2}-\frac{e^{-n}}{2}=2\frac{e^n}{2}=e^{n}=e^{fn}=\cosh(n)+\sinh(n)f$$
Now $f=-1$:
$$\cosh(n)-\sinh(n)=\frac{e^n+e^{-n}}{2}-\frac{e^n-e^{-n}}{2}=2\frac{e^{-n}}{2}+\frac{e^{n}}{2}-\frac{e^{n}}{2}=2\frac{e^{-n}}{2}=e^{-n}=e^{fn}=\cosh(n)+\sinh(n)f$$
Q.E.D.

Edit: I've seen the comments about the possibility of a different $f$, so I'm trying to prove it a different way.
Let's examine the ratio of the two side. If it's derivate is $0$, then their ratio is constant (assuming associativity, distributivity, commutativity):
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n}\bigg(\frac{\cosh(n)+f\sinh(n)}{e^{fn}}\bigg)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n}\bigg((\cosh(n)+f\sinh(n))e^{-fn}\bigg)=-fe^{-fn}(\cosh(n)+f\sinh(n))+e^{-fn}(\sinh(n)+f\cosh(n))=e^{-fn}(-f\cosh(n)+f\cosh(n)-f^2\sinh(n)+\sinh(n))=e^{-fn}\sinh(n)(1-f^2)=e^{-fn}\sinh(n)(0)=0$$
Now substitute $n=0$ into the fraction to get their ratio:
$$\frac{\cosh(0)+f\sinh(0)}{e^{f0}}=\frac{1+0f}{1}=1$$
So the $2$ sides are equal.
Q.E.D.

Comment: In its current form the second proof goes perfectly for split-complex numbers mentioned by @MishaLavrov, as they are commutative. I also hope it could be translated to noncommutative setting (as in general Clifford algebras), it seems very reasonable.

Comment: @arseniiv Thanks!  I think I'm unable to do it for noncommutative things, but someone smarter might be able to do it.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yeah, I’ve started to transport this proof and found out we need to take $(e^f)' = f'e^f$ as granted if we don’t want to prove it via series. I’d better stop it at that. :D [Here $f$ is a function.]

Comment: If $f$ does not commute with $n$, this statement is not true in general. For example, take $f = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $n = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$.